# Guide on how to use the "Update List Item Action" for a SharePoint 2010 Workflow in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, updatelistitems

This is my first time asking a question on here, so please bare with me on this.
I am creating a tool to collect averages based on a 1 to 5 scale over 4 different lists, and then collaborate those averages based off of the team chosen to another list so I can create a Chart WebPart.
Here's the run down:
-4 separate lists with multiple questions in a number column limited to a response of 1 - 5 "Required".
-In each list there is also a "Calculated Column" that will provide an "average".
(this part of the project works fine)

-I have created another List to collaborate the data (we will call this "List X) with the following columns
(Team) , (Date Of Report) , (List 1 Average) , (List 2 Average) , (List 3 Average) , (List 4 Average).

-Next I need to create workflows for each list that is triggered upon a new item created. This workflow will need to update the Average for each team on "List X"

-Finally I will create a Chart WebPart to display this information in a graph. I have already completed this whole process through Excel, but this requires user input and is not automated. Unless there is a way for me to update a specific cell in an excel spreadsheet based off of a created list item... I need to do this project through multiple lists and workflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was not having any items in "List X".. thus, I had nothing to update when using the "Update List Item" SharePoint 2010 Workflow Action in SPD. After adding the multiple Items, I then went back to Lists A, B, and C and updated the workflows to point to the corresponding items to update.

Answer (score 0):

Questions: Which version of SharePoint are you using, Online or on-premises? Why don’t you update the SharePoint List X directly with workflow, but build the process through Excel?

--

SharePoint Designer (2010) workflows do not have the ability to update Excel spreadsheet. You will have to build the workflow with [customization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg317441(v=office.14)).

If you are in SharePoint Online, you can use Microsoft Flow to update the Excel spreadsheet on SharePoint list item creation.

Reference: [Introducing Microsoft Flow integration in Excel.](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-microsoft-flow-integration-in-excel/)

Comment: My apologies, I am using a 3rd party hosted platform of SharePoint 2013 but only able to use SharePoint 2010 Workflows on SPD.

Comment: So the other lists have several yes/no questions as well as a number column associated to that column. (example: Does the Unit have good mental health? {yes/no} and then rate the overall mental health from 1 to 5. there will be several more questions within this specific list that an average is calculated upon submitting.. the average is a calculated column that displays in a view, but I also need to push that number to update another list (list X) automatically.

Comment: @BillyWhitley You can build a SharePoint 2010 workflow in one of these lists where you will manually create new items, and then trigger the workflow on item creation. The "Update List Item" action provides the ability to select the fields and corresponding values to update, so you will need to decide which fields in List X need to be put in. See a reference here: http://www.macaalay.com/2013/11/25/grouping-and-calculate-totals-from-one-sharepoint-list-to-another/